# Javascript : Inputfield Focus Event / trigger

Tags: javascript, html, web, user-input

I'm an Absoulute noob in js, as this is actually my first time even looking at it. My Issue isn't in js itself it's in understanding the connection between js and HTML. I'm Using a speicifc Software that is called " Ventuz " this software is node based, i'm using it to open a speicfic webpage. this webpage has inputfields ( user registration form). I'm trying to just get a trigger or something that tell's me that user pressed the Input Field so i can trigger something. A boolean can solve my issue. using ventuz, i can write JS code that can do that for me. This is what i currently have.

```
function myFunction() {
isFocused = true;
}
```

isFocused is a bool that i added in ventuz as an Output. I just want to play with this bool so i can trigger my stuff. My issue now is that I Don't understand how to make the above html code work with the webpage that the user is veiwing. how do i connect the actual inputfields on the page to my function?

This is the webpage :- [Click Here](https://www.eaglehills.com/register-interest)

According to my understanding i need to call my js function in the html like this :-

```
<input type="text" onfocus="myFunction(this)">
```

But i don't know how to call my js function in the html of the webpage. Remember that i'm using a software and using that software i'm using a web node that opens for me this page. And the software fully supports js and tweaking a webpage as you want.

I'm sorry for such a silly question. but i really can't figure it out :(

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if you have achieved this functionality, but this is possible in the ventuz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's say you added a div to test output.

```
<div id="message"></div>
<input type="text" onfocus="myFunction()">
```

And called it like this.

```
function myFunction() {
var isFocused = "It worked!";
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = isFocused;
}
```

This would output the results of your function.

This is a great resource to start out.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: Hello, thank you for putting time into this. How do i know the getElementById? As i explained above i'm running a webpage using a node. more info can be found here : http://www.ventuz.com/support/help/V4_06/NodeInteractionTouchWebBrowser.html

Comment: where can i put this <div id="message"></div>
<input type="text" onfocus="myFunction()">

Comment: id="message" determines the id that we are selecting. If we changed it:
<div id="message2"></div>
document.getElementById("message2")

Comment: the site contains 4 fields and each field has it's own ID. do i need to do this 4 times for each field?

Comment: <div id="message"></div> can be put anywhere in your html file.  I will add a complete answer of what this looks like in one page.

Comment: What confuses me is the software im using " Ventuz " using that node i just load a basic webpage but i dont understand how can i access the webpage html and connect my js to i t

Comment: In the <head></head> tag section add <script>your javascript goes here</script>

Comment: I believe my question makes no sense because my issue is rather with the software connectivity with the JS and since no one knows ventuz i don't think anyone will help. because i understand the answers that was given to me i used them and all worked fine. but when i try to put it inside the software it doesn't work. Thank you for you effort and it's fully appreciated. i will tick the answer right for your efforts thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
        <head>
        <script>
        function myFunction() {
        var isFocused = "It worked!";
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = isFocused;
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="message">So anything that goes on in the function with document.getElementById will display instead of this.</div>
        <input type="text" onfocus="myFunction()">
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I understand... But again, i can't access the HTML. the HTML is not mine how do i add call my function. the software supports JS . i think the best way is to get all InputFields from the webpage and add the function to it

Comment: if you put a browser in developer mode you can send javascript to the browser through the console tab, but that will only work for you in that specific web page.